# Creating a new function in AJAX

Tags: ajax

I saw some sample code like this in Javascript.  Is this AJAX?

```
(function() {
         /*some code*/

})();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this AJAX?

No. It's what's commonly referred to as an "immediately invoked function expression", or [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

```
(function() {
    /*some code*/
})();
//^^These parentheses cause the function to be executed
```

The wrapping pair of parentheses cause the construct to be an expression, rather than a declaration. That's necessary because you can't have an anonymous function declaration (you'd get a syntax error).

They are commonly used to introduce a new scope (producing what you may have heard referred to as a *closure*).